# Pointers and Their Values in C

Tags: c, pointers, cygwin

okay so part of this program i have to create, it's basically a game where a secret number is created and the user has to try and guess it, and i'm having some trouble with the pointers aspect of it. In my "generate_secret_number" function I have no issues in printing the value of the pointer, but in my "imTrying" function when I call the generate_secret_number function and try to print out the value of the pointer a I keep getting an error called "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile:" I was hoping someone could give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong, Thank you so much!

```
void generate_secret_number(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int num1,num2,num3;

    num1 = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    num2 = (rand() % 6);
    num3 = (rand() % 6);

    a = &num1;
    b = &num2;
    c = &num3;

    printf("the secret number is: %d%d%d", *a,*b,*c);
}

void imTrying(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int num1,num2,num3;
    generate_secret_number(a,b,c);
    printf("\n%d", *a);
}
```

Comment: How is `imTrying` called?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` go out of scope when `generate_secret_number` ends

Comment: Do not initialize the numbers (on the stack) inside the function if you expect to access them outside the function!

Comment: @dbush for now, it's called in the main function just so i can test it out, i'm just using this function to try and figure out how to get a value of a pointer from another function (if that makes sense)

Comment: @user10348124 That's *what* you're doing, but not *how*.  You need to show the code that calls that function to know exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

you're taking the addresses of the local variables to store them in local pointer variables (no effect whatsoever outside the function, the `printf` statement works which adds to the illusion)

```
a = &num1;
b = &num2;
c = &num3;
```

instead of copying their values in the passed-by-reference variables, proper way:

```
*a = num1;
*b = num2;
*c = num3;
```

(note that you can avoid using `num1`, etc...) by just doing:

```
*a = (rand() % 5) + 1;
*b = (rand() % 6);
*c = (rand() % 6);
```

of course, `a`, `b` and `c` must point to *valid memory* when calling the function.

```
int num1,num2,num3;
generate_secret_number(&num1,&num2,&num3);
```

We don't see the caller of the caller but since you say:

> I keep getting an error called "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile:"

it's probably because you caller (you're not showing) is like:

```
int *a,*b,*c;
imTrying(a,b,c);
```

since address pointed by `a` is not initialized, *but* isn't written to properly because of your other mistake, the program crashes with *undefined behaviour* when you're trying to *print* the value.

To fix it, in your context:

```
void imTrying(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    // int num1,num2,num3;  // useless
    generate_secret_number(a,b,c);        
}
```

caller:

```
int num1,num2,num3;    // valid memory
imTrying(&num1,&num2,&num3);
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", num1,num2,num3);
```

Comment: And to call the function, it should be `(&num1, &num2, &num3)`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you!! if i were to get rid of the num1,num2,etc. and change it to as you suggested (*a = (rand() % 5) + 1; etc.) how would i obtain the pointer value of 'a' in the other function? would i just call generate_secret_number and printf("%d", *a);

Comment: the pointers are the only way to change a value when calling a function. check my last edit (end of post snippet). The master caller just passes addresses of variables, then prints their _values_

Answer (score 0):

In

```
foo(int *bar)
{
    bar = 0x42;
}
```

it would be pointless (no pun intended) to modify the value of bar. (The value of a pointer is the address it holds). Since the pointer `bar` is a copy of the address that `foo()` is called with, nobody outside `foo()` would ever notice, that `bar` changed.

What you want to do instead, is to change the object `bar` points too:

```
foo(int *bar)
{
    *bar = 42;
}
```